# Bash: Sort parameter by size

Tags: bash, directory

I would like to sort all my directories that I give as parameter with my script by Size.
The "-S") stands for a case because it is part of a whole code

```
"-S")
 shift
 for f in "$@" ; do
 if [ -d "$f" ]
 then 
 echo "$f"
 fi
 done | sort
;;
```

This is how I sorted my parameters / directories by name, is there now a solution to sort it by size?

Thnx for reading / helping !

Comment: Doesn't `ls -S` already sort by size?

Comment: Yes but I need to sort my parameters, not the items that are in dere

Comment: I'm not quite following. One can give a list of file/dir patterns to `ls -S`, so could you clarify what you mean by "my parameters"? What are they and where are they?

Comment: When I do: . MyScript.sh -S Downloads Pictures Than it should check witch file is the biggest, if Downloads is the biggest than it comes first in the output: Downloads, Pictures

Comment: What is the size of a directory? The sum of the sizes of all included files? Like in `du`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with "mbratch" , ls -S option does sort by size and you can reverse that with a additional -r option . Whats the issue there ?

If i had to use another way i wouldn't use sort alone , i would rather do something like this :

```
 $ find . -size +20 | xargs du -sh | sort -n   ## put this in your for - list part
```

output :

```
 16K     ./.bash_history
 16K     ./libdata
 24K     ./.viminfo
 24K     ./test.sh
 28K     ./assign_chain/stuff/rpt
 52K     ./c_prac/t_malloc.exe
 52K     ./c_prac/wrt.exe
 64K     ./assign_chain/za_ch.csv
124K    ./assign_chain/stuff/b_ch.csv
```

does this help ?

Comment: Yes, ty very much but 1 litle question, is it possibel to turn the list around, so the 124 K comes first?

Comment: yeah ... there is a -r option to reverse that with sort ::  `find . -size +20 | xargs du -sh | sort -nr` , thats it

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps:

```
"-S")
  shift
  for f in "$@" ; do
    if [ -d "$f" ] ; then 
      echo "$f"
    fi
  done | xargs ls -Sd ;;
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a more explicit variant:

```
du -ks $(ls -d */)|sort -n|cut -f 2-
```

Comment: Your code is correct but how can I use this in my code above?

Comment: ooh nvm I found it, I had to put xargs before the sentence :) Ty for help